# sh script to open related URL based on possible nicknames

Tags: sh

I'm new to sh and I would like to get feedback on how I can improve my code.

The purpose is simple; I want to open the Jenkins JOB related to a service based on its possible aliases. If I map a service with its aliases, `READ_JOB="rj readjob read-job"`, I want to open it by calling the script `opendeploy readjob` or `opendeploy rj`.

The link between aliases and URLS to open was easy; an associative array worked.
But I wanted to link: Service Name, Job URL and Possible Services Aliases.
I Google to see if this can be done. But it looks like `sh` does not support nested arrays. I have created 2 arrays with the same keys.

```
#!/bin/bash

__READ_JOB="db-restore"

##Services x Aliases
declare -A SERVICES=(
    ["${__READ_JOB}"]="rj readjob read-job"
)

#Services x Jobs Links
declare -A JOBS_URL=(
    ["${__READ_JOB}"]="https://relatedJobUrl.com"
)

function opendeploy(){
  build=0
  rootJenskinsUrl='https://defaultUrlIfNoParameters.com/'
  urlToOpen=$rootJenskinsUrl
    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
      __getJobLink "$1"
          if [ "$1" = -b ] || [ "$1" = --build ]; then
            build=1
          fi
          if [ "$1" = -h ] || [ "$1" = --help ]; then
            ##Calling the method that explains how to use if the user use the "-h or -help"
            __usage
            return
          fi
      shift
  done

    ##Checking if -b parameter was filled, so we can append a build parameter at the end of the url
    if [ "$build" = "1" ] && [ "$urlToOpen" != "$rootJenskinsUrl" ]; then
      urlToOpen+='/build?delay=0sec'
    fi

  open $urlToOpen
}

__usage()
{
    ##This is why I need the association with the service name to well display: Service - Possible Aliases
    echo "usage: opendeploy service [[ [-b]] | [-h]]\n (no parameters opens root Jenkins URL)\n"

    echo "Possible Services - Aliases:\n"
    for k in "${(@k)SERVICES}"; do
      echo "$k -" "$SERVICES[$k]"
    done

}

function __getJobLink() {
    for k in "${(@k)SERVICES}"; do
      for alias in $SERVICES[$k]
      do
        if [ "$alias" = "$1" ]; then
          urlToOpen=${JOBS_URL[$k]}
        fi
      done
    done
}
```

I see points of improvements:

- Not to use global variables at the beginning of the script.
- Find a way to not create 2 associative arrays.

**PS**: This is running in a ZSH profile. I needed to adapt because bash was not recognising some things.

I do not wait to someone 'solve it' for me. I want suggestions on what I could do to improve my code.